# Почему попытка сравнить объекты вызывает исключение `NullPointerException`?

Tags: java, equals, тернарный-оператор, логические-выражения

Почему при `name` равном `null` у обоих сравниваемых объектов в закомментированом возврате возникает исключение `NullPointerException`, а во втором возврате - нет?

```java
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Cat cat = (Cat)obj;
//        return this.name == cat.name || this.name != null ? this.name.equals(cat.name) : cat.name == null;
        return this.name == cat.name || this.name != null && this.name.equals(cat.name);
}
```

Comment: Потому что операция `&&` ленивая и во втором случае дальше выражение не вычисляется.

Comment: А в первом случае почему вычисляется `this.name.equals(cat.name)` при `name == null` у обоих объектов? Ведь `||` тоже укороченная операция, да и в тернарном операторе тоже должно вычисляться второе выражение.

Comment: Приоритет тернарного оператора(?:) меньше, чем у `||`, поэтому получается так `(this.name == cat.name || this.name != null) ? this.name.equals(cat.name) : cat.name == null;` и если оба `null`, то выполняется `this.name.equals(cat.name)`. Можно исправить, поставив в скобки выражение с тернарным оператором

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как приоритет тернарного оператора ниже, чем приоритет оператора `||`, первый (закомментированный) оператор `return` эквивалентен такому коду:

```
if (this.name == cat.name || this.name != null) 
  return this.name.equals(cat.name); 
else 
  return cat.name == null;
```

Оператор `||` (как и оператор `&&`) -- это оператор с т. наз. короткой схемой вычисления (short circuit). Это значит, что если значение выражения, стоящего слева от оператора, однозначно определяет значение всего выражения (т. е. значение выражения уже не зависит от того, что стоит справа от оператора), то остаток выражения, стоящий справа от оператора, не вычисляется. Для оператора `&&` вычисление прекращается, если слева от него получилось `false` -- что бы ни было справа от оператора (обозначим это `x`), значение выражения `false && x` не может быть `true`. Для оператора `||` вычисление прекращается, если слева получилось `true`, т.к. результат всего выражения в любом случае будет `true`.

В вашем примере в том случае, если поля `name` обоих объектов равны `null`, условие `this.name == cat.name` оказывается истинным и выполняется код

```
 return this.name.equals(cat.name);
```

то есть происходит попытка обращения к объекту (вызов метода `equals()`) по ссылке `this.name`, значение которой -- `null`. Эта попытка и вызывает исключение.

---

P.S. При использовании в логических выражениях c операторами `&&` и `||` вызовов методов, которые имеют побочные эффекты (т. е. кроме вычисления и возврата значения делают что-то еще), типа

```
  if (a == b || этотМетодМожетОказатьсяНеВызван() ) ...
```

очень легко наделать ошибок. И если даже ошибок нет, такой код легко может быть понят неправильно, значит ошибку может сделать тот, кто будет этот код изменять/сопровождать. С такими вещами нужно всегда быть чрезвычайно осторожным, а лучше их вообще избегать.